# Is there a way to deserialize an object that needs to be constructed with a non-default constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

Ok, basics: C# 10, .Net 6, serializing to XML

Sample code to illustrate the problem, the real class being more complicated.

```
    public class Test<T> where T : struct, IComparable<T>
    {
        [XmlIgnore()]
        public T SomeOtherValue { get; private set; }

        public T Value { get; set; }

        protected Test() {
            // Just for serialization
        }

        public Test(int someOtherValue_)
        {
            SomeOtherValue = someOtherValue_;
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Test<int> IntValue { get; set; } = new() { SomeOtherValue = 42, };
        public Test<int> IntValue2 { get; set; } = new() { SomeOtherValue = 43, };
    }
```

With the above classes if I deserialize Data and IntValue is not in the XML stream, IntValue.SomeOtherValue == 42, but once I've serialized/deserialized the object, SomeOtherValue == 0, because the parameterless constructor for IntValue is run, and I just get the default for SomeOtherValue.

Think of SomeOtherValue as a programmer defined limit, so it can't be in the output file and since SomeOtherValue varies, it can't be static or defined in the parameterless constructor.  Additionally, there's code in set for Value and it needs SomeOtherValue to be set before Test is deserialized, so it can check constraints.

I can set IntValue.SomeOtherValue after loading, but as Data gets more complicated and has other classes in it that contain Test (and some of those have classes in them that contain Test) it becomes a big mess.

Is there some way that I can control construction of IntValue (without it being stupidly onerous) or better yet, a method where deserialization will use the object I've already created (via the new in Data).

Comment: Please note that code shown in the post *does not* have "non-default constructor"... You may want to adjust title (or code) to match.

Comment: If `SomeOtherValue ` isn't in the serialized data, maybe it shouldn't be in the class you're using the deserialize the data. You need a DTO class that exactly matches the data schema. You would then have a separate business class that includes `SomeOtherValue` that you would populate from the DTOs. That is the place where you'd apply your system limits, separate from the deserialization logic, so that you have complete control over what constructors are used.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I made some changes, but I'm not sure it makes it any clearer

Comment: @JohnWu Maybe, but that adds a lot of boilerplate both for getting data out of deserializing class and back in when it's serialized and will make us maintain two hierarchies classes that match either other, one for serializing and one for internal use/containing constraints.

Comment: Please re-read [mre] guidance. The change you've made makes code completely invalid as it will no longer compile (and you made it painfully clear that you did not confirm that sample posted in the question actually shows the problem) :(

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It showed the problem without the constructor you seemed to feel I needed, as that was my distilled test case to try things myself. With or without the non-default constructor, SomeOtherValue is being set in class Data and it is <not> being set with being deserialize

Comment: You could absolutely use reflection to find a constructor that takes all the serialized parameters, and possibly also comparing the parameter names. Some libraries can do things like that, but if your library does not support this it is probably easier to just make a DTO  object for easy serialization, and then convert it to a domain object.